# Globally changing Angular root route without changing routerLinks

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, routerlink

Currently I have routes set up something like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", redirectTo: "route1", pathMatch: "full"},
  {path: "route1", children: [
    {path: "", redirectTo: "subRoute1", pathMatch: "full"},
    {path: "subRoute1", component: SubRouteComponent}
  ]}
]
```

Which redirects to {domain}/route1/subRoute1 with accessing just {domain}.

Then in my components I have something like

```
<a [routerLink]="['/route1/subRoute1']">Link</a>
```

=============================

**MY PROBLEM:**

=============================

I want to add a new root url path to the entire app that is applied to all routes, **but I don't want to have to go change all *[routerLink]* instances to point to this new path.**

So for example, I want to change the routing like so, where **site1** is the new root url path:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", redirectTo: "site1", pathMatch: "full"},
  {path: "site1", children: [
    {path: "", redirectTo: "route1", pathMatch: "full"},
    {path: "route1", children: [
      {path: "", redirectTo: "subRoute1", pathMatch: "full"},
      {path: "subRoute1", component: SubRouteComponent}
    ]}
  ]}
]
```

And then I'd have to change routerLinks to

```
<a [routerLink]="['/site1/route1/subRoute1']">Link</a>
```

As far as I know, I would have to change all **[routerLink]** instances in the code to reflect this new url path change, **WHICH I'M TRYING TO AVOID**.

I could potentially have 100s of [routerLink] references, on top of needing the ability to change that root path often.

The solution I'm trying to work on right now is detecting a "NavigationStart" routing call and modifying the path at that point to prepend the new root path, but I don't think it's going to work like I hoped.

Also, this is another way of handling it: https://angular.io/guide/router#changing-heroes-to-superheroes

But I want to avoid having a bloated routing config.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you can't avoid this. The problem is in how your [routerLink] 's are written. You should use relative navigation, not absolute. Here is how you should rewrite your links, so that you can change your root-level routes without any troubles:

```
[routerLink]="['../../parent']"
[routerLink]="['../sibling']"
[routerLink]="['./child']"   
[routerLink]="['child']"
```

Answer (score 1):

So what I understand is that you want to **seamlessly** add another level of hierarchy into your routes array, without having to affect the existing **routeLink**s inside your entire application.

You'll just have to modify the existing routes array like this

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", redirectTo: "site1/route1", pathMatch: "full"},
  {path:"route1",redirectTo:"site1/route1"},
  {path: "site1", children: [
    {path: "", redirectTo: "route1", pathMatch: "full"},
    {path: "route1", children: [
      {path: "", redirectTo: "subRoute1", pathMatch: "full"},
      {path: "subRoute1", component: SubRouteComponent}
    ]}
  ]}
]
```

So in essence, for the default (empty, domain only) route, we gave the hierarchal redirection using "**site1/route1**" and for existing routes that start with **route1** we created a redirect rule like

```
{path:"route1",redirectTo:"site1/route1"},
```

so that existing links don't disturb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well for me.

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
export const routePrefix = "site1";
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", redirectTo: routePrefix, pathMatch: "full"},
  {path: routePrefix, children: [
    {path: "", redirectTo: "route1", pathMatch: "full"},
    {path: "route1", children: [
      {path: "", redirectTo: "subRoute1", pathMatch: "full"},
      {path: "subRoute1", component: SubRouteComponent}
    ]}
  ]}
]
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import {routePrefix} from "./app-routing.module";
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      if (!(new RegExp(routePrefix)).test(event["url"])) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl(routePrefix + event["url"]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Another option** I discovered is just using the *--base-href* arg with the *ng build* command. This will only work if you want to globally add a prefix (or domain subdirectory) to all routes

```
ng build --base-href site1
```